# Problem about logic

Tags: logic

A Mathematics lecturer can’t find a nice exercise for the final exam paper of his course. Then he makes up his mind and gives the following one-line exercise:

Write an exercise you think suitable for this exam, and solve it.

When he corrects the papers, he finds out that - just under the text of this exercise - one of his students has worked out the following two lines:

Write an exercise you think suitable for this exam, and solve it.
Write an exercise you think suitable for this exam, and solve it.

Now, the question is:
Is this a correct answer to the exercise?
If it’s not, modify it so that it becomes a correct answer.

I think it should be modified, because to solve the first sentence i need to solve the second and then i should solve the third, but to solve the third i need to write another exercise and solve it, so he should write infinite lines. 
But i don't think this could be the correct answer.
So i don't know how to solve it, also there is  more than one answer

Comment: Is that logic? It sounds more like natural language and [its] semantics.

Comment: @AsafKaragila english.stackexchange?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I would say that "how can we troll this question in a _mathematical_ way" is a valid question for this site with respect to topic (of course, there might be other flaws, like being opinion-based and so on). I think the OP asks about mathematical way to tie the loose ends (e.g. avoiding the infinite sequence of sentences), not about semantics of a particular wording of the cited phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution would be:

Excercise: Write an exercise you think suitable for this exam, and solve it. Solution: see Excercise and its Solution.

Then it is recursive in its definition. It relies on self reference and the lecturer considering the question as posed a suitable question. Logically this must be, since they posed it. And lecturers don't pose unsuitable questions (if economists can assume rational behavior, so can I).

Comment: So you obtain a sort of circularity. Is it a paradox ? Has it something to do with the discussion about the possibility of building paradoxes (like *the Liar*) avoiding self-reference ? (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yablo's_paradox)

Comment: Almost perfect, the problem is that your "Solution" is not a part of "Exercise" and so "see Exercise" is not a full solution (it lacks a solution you requested). I would say that "Solution: see Exercise and its Solution." would be better.

Comment: @dtldarek agreed. I have modified my answer.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA not a paradox. It is just self-referential.